# Active Record で複数カラムの IN 検索を行いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

今、以下のように、あるテーブル (たとえば、 `users`) の属性のタプルがあったとします。

```
attr_pairs = [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'piyo']]
```

ここから、 sql でいうところの複数カラムの IN 句によって絞りこみをかけたいです。

```
-- こんなデータが取りたい
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`attr1`, `attr2`) IN ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'piyo'));
```

これは、 Rails (Active Record) ではどのように実現されますか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

複数カラム IN は rails では(一旦文字列を介さないかぎり)できません。

ただ、同等の検索結果は、Rails 5 以上であるならば、`or`を用いて実現できます。

```
attr_pairs.map do |attr1, attr2|
  User.where(attr1: attr1).where(attr2: attr2)
end.reduce(&:or)
# => SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
#    WHERE ((`users`.`attr1` = 1 AND `users`.`attr2` = 'foo' OR
#            `users`.`attr1` = 2 AND `users`.`attr2` = 'bar') OR
#           `users`.`attr1` = 3 AND `users`.`attr2` = 'piyo')
```